# The Responsive grid in qliksense do not work in widget extension

Tags: grid, widget, responsive, qliksense

folks!

I m trying to create a widget qliksense card responsive but dont work its return one column always I need that work responsive em broke in another row in responsive mode.

Does Anybody knows?

```
<qw-console  log="data">

         
         <div   class="container" ng-repeat="row in data.rows track by $index">
         <div class=' sombra'>{{row.cells[0].qText}}</div> 
            
            <br/>
        </div>
</qw-console>
```

my css has:

```
.container {
 display: grid;
 
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(19rem, 1fr));
 grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 100px) ;

 grid-gap: 15px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this question:

```
<qw-console  log="data">

         <div class="container">
            <div    ng-repeat="row in data.rows track by $index">
                <div class=' sombra'>{{row.cells[0].qText}}</div> 
            
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
</qw-console>
```